# Sending emails from google doc spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Workign on a script to send out emails when job has been completed. I added in a piece which I thought would prevent from emailing twice. Having trouble figuring out why.

```js
function sendEmail() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) 

  {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1];
    var message = "Correction Completed for " + row[2]; 
    var subject = "Correction Completed";
    var emailSent = row[9];

    if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT") //prevent sending duplicate messages
    {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
    }

  }

}
```

My thinking was putting the sendEmail portion in an if statement, it would not send. However it still sends an email regardless. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your `var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)`. Try to change `3` to something bigger than `9`, because of `var emailSent = row[9];`. When you read `emailSent` pay attention to read previous written status.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify 2 things :

1. When you use `sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);` you are indeed writing the EMAIL-SENT label in column 9 because getRange works with column numbers starting from 1.
2. When yo read data in an array (that comes from a sheet range) the index in this array **starts on 0**, that means that you should use `var emailSent = row[8];` to get the corresponding 9th value
3. (yes I know I said 2 things ;-) The array must at least contain this 9th column so you should read it using an appropriate range : `var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 9)` for example...*(but not less than 9 in any case)*

Hoping this is clear enough.